# Angular 1.X Typescript Controller Undefined when using SystemJS

Tags: angularjs, typescript, systemjs

I am using TypeScript with AngularJS 1.5.x and in my tsconfig it all gets compiled down into SystemJS code. Now the issue I am having is only in controller classes that have an import at the top (see example below). If I take these imports out everything works just fine and the controller is found, but if I put them in, the controller is wrapped in a System.register block and it is not found when I go to my view.

I'm a beginner with SystemJS so I'm hoping I am just doing something really dumb, but it has been driving me nuts as to why when I have the imports it does not work.

```
    import { testService} from '../services/test.service';
    import { testClass} from '../models/testClass';

     namespace app.controllers {

         export class testController{
             private testService: any;

             constructor(public $http: angular.IHttpService) {

            }

            getData(): any {

            }

         }

        angular.module('app')
            .controller('testController', testController);
         }
```